How to Add Bearer Token for Authentication in Video.js Using Nuxt 3?
I'm developing a Nuxt 3 application where I need to play videos using Video.js. The video files are protected and require a bearer token. I'm trying to add the token to the request headers in the Video.js setup, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.
Video player component
<template>
  <div :class="id ? 'w-72 h-auto' : ''">
    <video
      ref="videoPlayer"
      class="video-js vjs-default-skin w-full h-full"
      controls
      preload="auto"
      :poster="poster"
    >
      <source :src="videoSrc" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
     {{ videoSrc }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useNuxtApp } from '#app'
import { ref, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount } from 'vue'

const userAccessToken = useCookie('user_access_token')

const props = defineProps({
  videoSrc: { type: String, required: false },
  poster: { type: String, default: '' },
  id: { type: String, default: '' }
})

const videoPlayer = ref(null)
const { $videojs } = useNuxtApp()
const poster = ref()

const fetchPosterAsBlob = async (posterUrl) => {
  if (!posterUrl) return ''

  try {
    const response = await fetch(posterUrl, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userAccessToken.value}`
      }
    })
    if (!response.ok) {
      console.error('Failed to fetch poster image')
      return ''
    }
    const blob = await response.blob()
    return URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching poster image:', error)
    return ''
  }
}

onMounted(async () => {
  if (!userAccessToken.value) {
    console.error('Missing user access token for video playback.')
    return
  }


  const posterBlobUrl = await fetchPosterAsBlob(props.poster)
  poster.value = posterBlobUrl

  const player = $videojs(videoPlayer.value, {
    autoplay: false,
    controls: true,
    responsive: true,
    fluid: true
  })  
  
  player.ready(() => {
// Ensure VHS is available
const vhsOptions = player.tech()?.vhs || player.tech()?.hls;
    
    if (vhsOptions) {
      vhsOptions.xhr.beforeRequest = (options) => {
        options.headers = options.headers || {}
        options.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${userAccessToken.value}`
        return options
      }
    } else {
      console.error('VHS or HLS is not properly initialized.')
    }
  })

  onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    if (player) {
      player.dispose()
    }
  })
})
</script>

<style scoped>
.video-js {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>


When excute code i got 'VideoPlayer.vue:82 VHS or HLS is not properly initialized.' error
I want to add the bearer token to the headers of the video request so that Video.js can authenticate and play the video. I've tried using the xhr.beforeRequest method within the player.ready callback, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach or if I'm missing something.

the error is one you yourself created in the if/else to be logged when vhsOptions is false, meaning player.tech()?.vhs || player.tech()?.hls is also false.  the code block where you set the Bearer token therefore doesn't run.  I'm not familiar with this library but this looks more like improper initialization.  It doesn't seem like you're even making it to an actual video request yet, so concentrating on the bearer token feels like a red herring.
